# Does TagLibSharp lock a file?

Tags: .net, winforms, taglib-sharp

Unfortunately I don't have direct access to my code at the moment, but the application does the following:

- Get a `string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.mp3", SearchOptions.AllDirectories);`
- Iterate over each file in files and get a generic Tag object (not an IDV3 one specifically, or whatever the format is called)
- Build a string with a new filename {track no} - {track name} from the Tag object and add it to a list
- `File.Copy(files[i], newFileName, true)` to rename the file (copy to the same directory with a new name)

The `File.Copy` crashes and it tells me another process is using the file. I know for a fact nothing else is using these files, but something somewhere in my code must be locking them and I don't know what, nor how to deduce which bit it is.

I've tried adding `myTagObject.Save(); myTagObject.Clear(); myTagObject = null;` in case TL# was locking the file but I can't think of anything more I could do there to release it.

Comment: Probably does.  Doubt the Tag object has anything to do with it.  Tag doesn't implement IDisposable.  But, oh, look, TagLib.File ***does*** implement IDisposable.  Probably because it locks the file.  Do you dispose the File after you're done using it?

Comment: I'm not certain if I create a `TagLib.File` object, I think I just create the `Tag` from the file path in `string[] files` but I'll have to check into that! Thanks.

Comment: @Will Alrigth I tried creating the `TagLib.File` object, creating the `Tag` object, getting data from the `Tag`, then I close it and assign null. Dispose & assign null to the `File` as well. Same error-- File in use :(

Comment: Can you create a complete, self contained example in a console application that reproduces the issue?  Perhaps you're locking the file somewhere else in your codebase?  A repro would help.